# How to stub ShopifyAPI::Theme.all request in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, shopify-app

I'm doing RSPEC testing and need to stub or make a fake request to return static hash.

**I have**:

```
ShopifyAPI::Theme.all.select{|t| t.role == "main"}.first
```

I know to stub that `ShopifyAPI::Theme.all`,

**Like**: `allow(ShopifyAPI::Theme).to receive(:all).and_return( test_main_theme )`

And I have helper method.

```
 def test_main_theme
  {
   "id": 2335539244,
   "name": "Debut",
   "created_at": "2017-12-22T18:13:24-05:00",
   "updated_at": "2018-04-11T20:16:17-04:00",
   "role": "main",
   "theme_store_id": 796,
   "previewable": true,
   "processing": false
 }
end
```

**but** having `.select{|t| t.role == "main"}.first` is another way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
allow(ShopifyAPI::Theme).to receive_message_chain(:all, :select, :first)
  .and_return(test_main_theme)
```

see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains

Comment: Can you please check this one, if will work..
ShopifyAPI::Asset.find("snippets/x.liquid", :theme_id => theme.id)
allow(ShopifyAPI::Asset).to receive(:find).with("snippets/x.liquid", {theme_id: 2335539244}).and_return( test_asset_hash )

Comment: lgtm at quick glance ;)